# Blocked a website in DD-WRT but it doesn't block all its subdomains, is there a way?

Tags: wireless-router, dd-wrt, blocking, subdomain

I blocked a site (http://exampleurl.com/) in DD-RWRT's control panel and it worked, but just for that exact URL, it didn't block the entire website (http://exampleurl.com/stuff/etc) and all other sub-domains can still be accessed.

Is there a way to make DD-WRT effectively block an **entire** website and its sub-domains?

Comment: Would blocking the IP suffice?

Comment: @DaveRook that site uses AWS, does cloud servers still have the same IP across the board?

Comment: @DaveRook OK so I tried the IP way and it didn't work, it didn't even block the main page like the URL did, any ideas?

Comment: Does this page help? http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Access_Restrictions

Comment: @DaveRook Thats what I used in the first place.

Comment: At the bottom of the page it makes a note about using old firmware. Is your firmware up to date?

Comment: I assume you're doing it like this http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eHQaCK3iYxA

Comment: @DaveRook Yeah, exactly like that, it didn't work

Comment: OK, I don't know enough about this router, however, I would email the company direct at this point.

Comment: Its a dlink DIR600, doubt they'll help since it isn't factory firmware

Answer (score 1):

You can use for example `exampleurl.com` in **Website Blocking by Keyword** field. This will disable URLs links which containing `exampleurl.com` string.

Also you can use any word from an URL to block it.
So if you want to disable some subdomain you can use the string as for example `sub1.exampleurl.com` and it'll be blocked but another subdomains like `sub2.exampleurl.com` will stay accessible.

If you want to shut down every shop you can set the `shop` in the **Website Blocking by Keyword** field and every link which contains the word `shop` will be blocked, and it does not matter if it is `http://shop.anyurl.anydomain` or `http://anyurl.anydomain/shop`.

Filtering of `https://` URLs is problematic because they are encrypted in the communication and the router does not see them.